# HTML 5 filter language or some analog of filter language?

Tags: javascript, html, filter, glsl, hlsl

Is there in HTML 5 filtering language or some analog of filter language? Something like GLSL / HYDRA / HLSL or just JS pixel filter/shader lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the closest thing to what you want is SVG filters, or perhaps canvas+JS. You certainly won't find anything standard that will work with IE. You'll probably have to come up with a hybrid of SVG/VML/ActiveX/Canvas and JS or just use Java. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this, but since the question seems to be related to shaders, you might be interested in [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).